# Instantiate 2D Array of objects using multiple classes

Tags: java, arrays, oop, object

I've hit a wall with my assignment.

I've created a 2D array of objects that I need to instantiate using various classes.

There's a whole bunch of other requirements, but my main concern (at the moment) is I can't figure out why I'm getting an array of ' c ' instead of ' . '

Here is a section of my code, with Driver class, Item class, Dot class, and Array class.

Any help would be much appreciated.

```
    public class Driver
    {

      public static void main(String[] args) 
      {
      Driver a = new Array();
      ((Array) a).runArray();
      }
   }
```

---

```
    public abstract class Item extends Driver
    {

     private char component;

     public Item (char c)
     {
       component = 'c';
     }


    public char display()
   {
     return component;
   }


  //create a new array of objects.
  Item[][] array = new Item [10][10];

  }
```

---

```
 public class Dot extends Item
 {

   public Dot () 
   {
     super('.');
   }
```

---

```
 import java.util.*;

 public class Array extends Item
 {

   Array() 
  {
    super(c);
  }

  Random randGen = new Random();
  private int CoordX = randGen.nextInt(3);
  private int CoordY = randGen.nextInt(3);


    public void runArray()
    {
        setArray();
        displayArray(); 
    }


    private void setArray()
    {
        for (int row = 0; row < array.length; row++) 
            for (int col = 0; col < array[row].length; col++)
                    array[row][col] = new Dot();
    }


    private void displayArray()
    {
        for (int row = 0; row < array.length; row++){ 
            for (int col = 0; col < array[row].length; col++){
                System.out.print(array [row][col].display()+"\t"); 
            }
            System.out.println("\n");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Because no matter how you call the constructor of `Item` it will always be char `c`

```
public Item (char c)
     {
       component = 'c';
     }
```

change it to

```
public Item (char c)
     {
       component = c;
     }
```

Comment: @user4824195 Don't forget to mark this answer as correct.